# why is the card not comming on top?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

hey the content of the card is not comming on the top .it is just hiding behind the background and i want to bring it on the top .  note i am using only bootstrap 4

html

```
<section id="pricing" class="">
<h1 class="text-center  text-uppercase my-5 py-5">services</h1>
<div class="container py-5 my-5">
<div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
<div class="col-10 m-auto col-md-3  bg-white  py-5" id="card-pricing">
<h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">basic</h1>
<hr class="my-4">
<p class="lead text-center">
$ <span class="size-grt font-weight-bold ">20 </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odio consectetur, provident molestiae a ad possimus ipsam harum delectus.
</p>
<hr class="my-4">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
<button class="btn purchase-btn text-uppercase">purchase</button></div>
</div>
<div class="col-10 m-auto col-md-3 bg-white pricing-middle py-5" >
<h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">basic</h1>
<hr class="my-4">
<p class="lead text-center">
$ <span class="size-grt font-weight-bold ">20 </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odio consectetur, provident molestiae a ad possimus ipsam harum delectus.
</p>
<hr class="my-4">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
<button class="btn purchase-btn text-uppercase">purchase</button></div>
</div>
<div class="col-10 m-auto col-md-3 bg-white  py-5" id="card-pricing">
<h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">basic</h1>
<hr class="my-4">
<hr class="my-4">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
<button class="btn purchase-btn text-uppercase">purchase</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

scss file

```
#pricing{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585314062340-f1a5a7c9328d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80') no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%,100% 75%,50% 100%,0% 75%,0% 0% );
}
```

right now the cards are looking like this https://ibb.co/GWVhGY6  and 
 i have nott given you the styling of cards

Answer (score 0):

change the z-index -1 to 999, to takes your card layer on top.

```
#pricing{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585314062340-f1a5a7c9328d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80') no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%,100% 75%,50% 100%,0% 75%,0% 0% );
}
```

Comment: but why do i need to do this

Comment: provide your full html

Comment: take the google drive link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QOT2OPzjHqRbSH_GkzBqD2mKmo7xfK4d?usp=sharing